# Django view isn't called while performing an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I'm trying to setup an AJAX call in order to call a Django view, perform some calculations and then return the ouput into my html page. Unfortunately, the view doesn't seem to be reached. Not sure what is wrong but I have very limited AJAX experience.
The idea is that when my slider sees a change in value, it triggers the AJAX call. The trigger seems to work as it displays my alert pop-up. But that's it, nothing else happens.
Could you please help?

Here is my html/AJAX code:

```
 <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <span>Option 1 Imp. Vol.</span>
    <input class="toChange" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" type="range" value="{{Sigma}}" min="0" max="150" step="0.1" oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value" />
    <input class="toChange" id="amount" type="number" value="{{Sigma}}" min="0" max="150"  step="0.1"oninput="rangeInput.value=amount.value" />
  </div>

<label>Ajax Test:</label>
<span id="Atest">

 <script type="text/javascript">
   function inputChange () {
        var Sigma = document.getElementById("rangeInput").value;
        alert();
        $.ajax({
                url: '/finance/templates/optionstrategies/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'Sigma': Sigma,
                },
                //dataType: "json",
                success: function(optionVal) {
                document.getElementById("Atest").innerHTML = optionVal;
                }
        }); 
    }

    $(".toChange").change(inputChange); 
 </script>
```

And here is my view.py:

```
def optionStrategies(request):
    errors=''
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        print('ok')
        Type = request.POST.get('Type')
        V = request.POST.get('V')
        Q = request.POST.get('Q')
        S = request.POST.get('S')
        K = request.POST.get('K')
        r = request.POST.get('r')
        t = request.POST.get('t')
        Sigma = request.POST.get('rangeInput')

        BS = BlackScholes(Type = 'Vanilla', S = float(S), K = float(K), sig = float(Sigma)/100, r = float(r)/100, t = float(t)/365)
        optionVal = BS[0]
        print(optionVal)

        optionVal = json.dumps(optionVal)
        return HttpResponse(optionVal, content_type='application/json')
```

Edit1: adding urls.py code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.home, name="homepage"),
    path('optionstrategies/', views.optionStrategies, name="optionstrategies"),
    path('impliedvolatility/', views.impliedVolatilityHtml, name="impliedvolatility"),
```

Comment: can you show your urls.py

Comment: Just edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: I do not think that your url is right: /finance/templates/optionstrategies/ Is your project called templates? Shouldn't it just be /finance/optionstrategies/

Comment: I guess you're right. I mixed up the folder path to my page with my url. Nevertheless, even after trying /finance/optionstrategies/ nothing worked. Any other idea?

Comment: It seems to work if I only use /optionstrategies/ as the url. So the issue was indeed related to the url. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the url. Replacing '/finance/templates/optionstrategies/' with '/optionstrategies/' did the trick.